# extract a part of txt file from String name to an empty line

Tags: java, file

I want to extract a part of a text file beginning with a String name and ending with an empty line

Here is what I tried:

```
public File CreateSubscripberFile(File file,String name) throws IOException
{

     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.equals(name))
            {
                while (((line = br.readLine()) != null) && (!(line.equals("\n"))))
                {
                             fw.write(line);
                             System.out.println(line);

                }   
            }      


        }
        br.close();
        fr.close();
        fw.close();

return f;
}
```

but I get the original file as result!

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
(line = br.readLine())!=null)
```

with:

```
(!(line = br.readLine()).equals(""))
```

null in this example would mean 'there is not more lines', and .equals(""), looks for empty line.

Answer (score 0):

it's done by edit he code like this

```
    public File CreateSubscripberFile(File file,String name,String fname) throws IOException
{
    File f= new File(fname);
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.equals(name))
            { 
                String line1 = br.readLine() ;
                while(line1 != null && !line1.isEmpty() )
                {

                    System.out.println(line1);
                    line1=br.readLine();
                }
            }
        }
        br.close();
        fw.close();
return f;
}
```